# fill textbox on datagrid row click

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to fill textboxes when a user clicks on a row. I don't want to use `grdUser..SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text` because my datagrid has a summary of the user details e.g. `name, SSNumber, email.` if I click on the row then I want all the user details should load into textboxes. How would I do that?

I would like to use a sql query but then my `where` clause should use `SSNumber` but not sure that's best practise.

C# or vb help welcome.

Comment: Handle the SelectedItem event, and read all its info, then assign it to the textbox. Assuming all the info you need is already loaded in the DataGrid, why would you need an sql query?

Comment: to maybe `SELECT all columns FROM table` and in `WHERE` clause filter them by unique ID then that one's info should be in textboxes. Sounds like a long stupid way typing this out.

Comment: My suggestion is the same, handle the SelectedItem event, execute your query upon even fireup, given the selected ID.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the relevant code you are working with so we can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Attributes to the Row created and when the user clicks that row redirect them to a page with the Id of the object you want to display. I know you are using a datagrid my example is using a GridView

For example on Row created

```
protected void ListGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType .DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes[ "onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';" ;
            e.Row.Attributes[ "onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';" ;
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            e.Row.Attributes[ "onclick"] = "Javascript:window.location = '" + ResolveClientUrl("~/PickList/ScanPickListItem.aspx" ) + "?PLRID=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ScreenRowId" ) + "'";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the index of the selected row then get the value of the specific cell

```
Dim dgv_active_Row as Integer= dgv.CurrentRow.Index
TextBox1.Text = dgv.Item(1, dgv_active_Row).Value
```

'1' is the index of the specific column  where you want to get the value of the textbox